# Netlogo, writing and calling a function

Tags: netlogo

I want to write a function where a list containing a set of agents are removed if a certain condition is satisfied. In this situation, if the turtle-own variable is set deceased? = true, remove them from the list. I have a bunch of lists and want to do that for all the lists, hence I am writing a function to do that. I am not sure how to write report within the function or whether even if it's necessary. Also how do I call the function

```
breed [traps trap]
breed [Cages cage]
breed [foxes fox]

traps-own[list-trapped-foxes]
Cages-own[list-caged-foxes]
foxes-own [deceased?]

to-report remove-agents [list-x]
foreach list-x[
  i ->
    ask i[
      if deceased? = True [
      let agent-to-be-removed self
      ask myself [
        set list-x remove agent-to-be-removed list-x
        report list-x
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
end

to renew-agents
  ask traps [remove-agents list-trapped-foxes]
  ask Cages [remove-agents list-caged-foxes]  
end
```

Comment: It is much more common in NetLogo to use agentsets than lists of agents. Can I just check that you actually need lists, because it changes the answer. You need lists if the order is important, or if you need multiple copies of the same agent for example.

Comment: This is just an example but in the model, I am writing I have added a lot of lists. So ideally I hope to keep it in the list format.

Answer (score 1):

a) It is rarely advisable (or even allowed) to modify a list while you are iterating through it, as you are trying to do here.

b) As JenB said, it would be wiser to use agentsets instead of lists if you can. (One reason you might need lists is if the same agent needs to be on the list more than once; preventing that might be a reason to use agentsets.

If list-x was an agentset, you would use: set list-x list-x with [not deceased?]

c) What you need for lists is the primitive "filter": I did not try it but this should work instead of your whole reporter: set list-x filter (not deceased?) list-x

(Remember always to see whether what you need has already been written before starting again, especially for a task as common as this!)

Comment: Aight steve, Jen B. Thanks for the advice, you guys may be correct. I have to amend lists most of the time when transferring agents. I'll try to modify it based on agentsets.